# Automatically generate differences from two latex sources

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, latexmk

Say for a use case of incremental review, I want to show from a previous revision to an existing one what has changed in the PDF rendering. Is there an existing tool which can do this?

I already version my latex sources through git, I simply want to generate a new file which indicates the changed elements in a highlight or different colour to quickly point to the changes for somebody reviewing.

Comment: If you can use `latexdiff` that is the best option (it has problems sometimes); otherwise I find this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/297285/16395 pretty fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Latexdiff creates a new tex file with a markup of the differences between two tex files: https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff?lang=en

Comment: Interesting. Can you add a minimal example that shows how this is used?